# Does the norm have a specific name?

Tags: terminology, normed-spaces

Does the norm $$\|f\|=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,T]}\int\limits^t_0|f(\tau)|\ d\tau$$ have a specific name?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. As $t \mapsto \int_0^t|f(\tau)|\, d\tau$ is monotone, the sup equals $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^T |f(\tau)|\,d \tau$, the $L^1([0,T])$-norm.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: So, more interesting would be $$\|f\|=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,T]}\left|\ \int\limits^t_0 f(\tau) \ d\tau \right|$$